# How to create a dictionary with keys as integer and definition as a numpy array?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I have created a CNN model that can predict hand signs. I have 10 classes ie. 0-9. 
the output of model.predict_classes() is a numpy array

ex. prediction of 5 is [5].

I want to an integer to be returned so that I can continue my calculations.

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
depth = 0
ps = 0
start_pros = 0
classifier = load_model('hand_gest.h5')
classifier.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])
number = []



def occurrence(lt):
    for num, sublist in groupby(lst):
        if len(list(sublist)) == 25:
            return num

while(1):
    try:
        ret, frame = cam.read()
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)
        roi = frame[100:400,200:500]
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(200,100),(500,400),(0,255,0),2) 
        cv2.imshow('curFrame',frame)
        cv2.imshow('roi',roi)


        img = cv2.resize(roi,(100,100))
        img = np.reshape(img,[1,100,100,3]) 
        classes = classifier.predict_classes(img)
        number = number.append(classes)
        pred_num = occurrence(number)
```

This is the error that occurs during execution.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not `number = number.append(classes)`, you need to just call append:

```
number.append(classes)
```

`append` modifies in-place the list and returns `None`, so in your code the second time the loop runs `number` will be None and thus the error happens.

Comment: is there a way where I can get an integer instead of a numpy array?

Comment: `classes[0]`? As long as your batch size is 1, that will do

Comment: my classes variable stores the predicted class which is of type nparray. But I need an integer. 
ex. classes variable hold value [3] (where 3 in nparray). But i want an Integer 3.

Comment: Yes. As long as you feed one image per batch to your network (which is the case for your sample code above), the network will produce one value as output. That means, `classes` has shape `(1,)`. This means, getting the "first" (and only) value of the array will give you the integer you want. You do that with `classes[0]`.